# Help! dragDrop event not firing for my TextArea control

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm working on a simple view in my app that allows a user to drag an item from a list control and drop it onto a textarea.

Seems the dragEnter event fires just fine, but the dragDrop event does not.

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to add the textarea as a drop target during my drag enter handler.  :P